# Fetch the Last 5 Records in ascending Order With out Sub query

Tags: mysql

I have my MySQL query below, here I need the last 5 records in ascending order

```
SELECT TransId  FROM `sf_transaction` ORDER by TransId DESC limit 5
```

My Output is given below which is in descending order

[image]

I need this in ascending order, don't want to use  subqueries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way without subquery.

```
(SELECT TransId
   FROM `sf_transaction`
   ORDER BY TransId DESC
   LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY TransId ASC
```